# Updating a large list of items using await, how can I speed this up?

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm updating a large list of items and setting prices.

for...

```
currentItem.attributes.menuItemPrice10 = currentItem.attributes.menuItemPrice1 + .28;
await this.menuItemsService.save(currentItem);
```

This works ok, but Angular seems to have limited threading options.

If I take the await out, then it just blows though the list, but checking the logs it doesn't update everything - so it's like it gives up on some of the updates because I didn't wait for it, right?

So, the alternative seems to be web workers - but it says that doesn't support running 'itself' as a web worker and has some platform limitations.  Not sure what that means, so looking for best practice on how to speed this up?

Thanks

Comment: Have you considered ```Promise.all```, im not actually sure if this will work, but I think mapping your items to promises of updates may cut it...

Comment: How large is the list? What is the save function doing? Are you showing the list on UI  or just saving it to the DB or backend?

Comment: Promise.all - no, didn't know about it, so looking at that.  Probably ~2000 rows per run, yes backend microservice save to DB, not showing list while it runs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your `save` is an asynchronous operation, e.g. a network request. If it actually uses something like `fs.writeFileSync` which blocks the whole process, then you can't speed it up.

There is [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) that allows you to wait for an array of Promises to resolve. Combine this with `.map` and you can perform bulk operations on lists of items:

```js
await Promise.all(items.map(item => this.menuItemService.save(item)));
// or if it's just a hardcoded small amount of operations:
await Promise.all([
    this.menItemService.save(previousItem),
    this.menItemService.save(currentItem),
    this.menItemService.save(nextItem),
]);
```